# C++ 11: conversion const int* to int* using unordered_set::push

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set, const-cast

I have this problem of conversion with this code using c++11 standard:

```
#include<unordered_set>
struct B
{
   int x, y;
};

class A
{
   struct hash
   {
      std::size_t operator()( int* const a ) const
      {
         return std::hash<int>()( *a );
      }
   };

   struct equal_to
   {
      std::size_t operator()( int* const a, int* const b ) const
      {
         return std::equal_to<int>()( *a, *b );
      }
   };

   private:
      std::unordered_set< int*, hash, equal_to > set;

   public:
      void push( const B& b )
      {
         set.insert( &b.x );
      }
};
```

Anyone know why is that? I can I solve the problem removing the "const" modifier in the argument of "push". But I don't want it because argument "b" isn't modified.

Edit.: My simplification of code has produced a unreferenced adress. I've make a struct B remove it.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The problem is in `set.insert(&a)`, where `a` has type `const int&`. The address of `a` has type "pointer to const int", but the set object is looking for a "pointer to (modifiable) int". That kind of `const` confusion is quite common, and warrants an answer.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you are storing the address of an object that may be a temporary object in your set. Once the `a` that was passed to the `push` method has gone out of scope the address is invalid and could lead to heap corruption or application crashes later if it is referenced (by say your `equal_to` method).

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having? Is there an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: The unrelated question: is there any important difference in passing int by value and passing int by const ref?

Comment: @maverik: not a relevant difference in this case

Answer (score 2):

The key of the `set` is declared as being a *pointer-to-int*, an `int*`. But this:

```
void push( const B& b )
{
    set.insert( &b.x );
}
```

is passing the address of a constant `int`, an `int const*`, hence the compiler error.

Removing the `const` from the argument would resolve the compiler error, as would making the key type an `int const*`, but both these solutions would:

- permit some other part of the program, with non-`const` access to a `B` instance that was passed to `push()`, to change a value of one of the keys within the set and break the set invariant:

  ```
  A a;

  B b1{17, 22};
  B b2{30, 22};

  a.push(b1);
  a.push(b2);

  b1.x = 30;  // set no longer contains unique keys.
  ```
- introduce a dependency of the `set` on the lifetime of the object referenced by `b`:

  ```
  A a;
  a.push({14, 23}); // a now contains a dangling pointer.
  ```

The safest solution is to store an `int` as the key, see http://ideone.com/KrykZw for online demo (thanks to [bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/430766/bitmask) for comment).

---

<strike>Possible solutions:</strike>

1. Dynamically copy `b.x`. Or,
2. Use `int const*` as the key. Or preferably (avoiding explicit dynamic allocation),
3. Use `int` as the key, instead of an `int*` (see http://ideone.com/KrykZw)

Comment: Storing an `int*` in a (hash-)set (or a regular set for that matter), while allowing the pointed-to-object to change and having the hash function compute the hash based on the pointed-to-object, will not only exhibit undefined behaviour but also quite certainly crash in any implementation I can think of. Your 3rd solution is the only one that makes sense. (Note that `b.x` might change even if `b` is passed as const ref into `push`.)

Comment: Thanks, 2 option is my favourite solution because I don't want to use copy-constructor.

Comment: @jefebrondem, what copy constructor?